# Components in react not rendering, despite having a key property

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i am fairly new to React and this is my first project with Redux.

I get some data and set it in the state-tree. When my reducer `ADD_PRODUCTS_TO_CART` runs, my `Products->render()` runs, but `Product->render()` does not, despite having a key.

Here is a gist, it was the most basic i could boil it down to. Hope it makes sense, i've included a file that represents the state of the tree, so you can see the data structure.

https://gist.github.com/hoodweb/e4005e4f1fc95682d4dd9bf87b81fe39

**TLDR:** Basically the stock decrements in the statetree, but is not rendered. What am i doing wrong?

**Update:** I have put in `console.log()` in all render methods, to see what is called. When i decrease the stock of my product, the product is not called. This is most likely due to the `.map(() => <Product/>)` i am doing. I tried changing my `key={}` property to include the stock like this:

`.map((obj) => <Product key={obj.ID.toString() + obj.Stock.toString()} data={obj} />)`

Which seems to work. But I do know how stable this is.

**Update2:** It seems that if i take my `data={}` property at put it into seperate properties like this 
`<Product key={obj.ID} stock={obj.Stock} title={obj.Title} price={obj.Price} beforePrice={obj.BeforePrice}`
it works. So that is my solution for now.

Comment: What are the values of your props inside of PRoducts?

Answer (score 1):

In `render` function of `Product` you got:

```
if (data.Variations) { //TODO: Variation logic
    return false;
}
```

Because in `data` you got `Variations` param, it goes through this scope (beacause `Variations` is not `null` or `undefined`) and returns null instead of rendering component.

remove `return false` and your code should work fine.

Comment: Hi. I've removed the data.Variations. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Besides, i've put in a `console.log()` in the render methods. And i know that the `product->render()` is not called

Comment: can you `console.log(products)` in `render` method of **Products**?

Comment: Yes. Here is the dump before and after the `ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART` action: https://gist.github.com/hoodweb/3a166936273258683c219bd3aca49d73

Do note that i changed the code back to `<Product key={obj.ID} data={obj} />` for this gist. To keep it relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like @kiarashws said, whenever you `return false` in your `render()` method, it doesn't render. Make sure to not render only when you don't want to.

Is commonly see code like this:

```
render() {
   if (props.shouldNotRender) 
      return null or false;

   return <div>
      ...
   </div>
}
```